# Is there a SQLite3 query generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am having a database in Ruby on Rails application using SQLite3. Knowing my table, is there an open source project which can provide me an easy way of creating sqlite queries?

For example, based on the table names and order, I have a the available joins, and then I can add my conditions based on my variables.

Comment: What's wrong with ActiveRecord?

Comment: If you look for a SQL-like generator you may take a look for [sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not.

Active record will provide you a lot of the functionalities you need to query, create and update records. It's not all that good at generating joins though.

The thing is, only you know the query you need to generate, hence there are very few "one-size-fits-all" query generator.  It's a bit like asking "is there a Ruby code generator for generating my application". Well no, because only you knows what needs to be coded.

I tempted to say, keep your infrastructure simple, code the few queries you need rather than "rocket-science" a fancy generator that'll be hard to maintain. If in then end you need to generate a query from various arguments, concatenate strings and you'll get there faster than the time you'd take to research a generator.